Play Store won't let me upload my .aab - Firebase Expo
Even at Expo 49 I used firebase and recaptcha but now with expo 50 recaptcha was stopped and I use react native firebase, I had never had problems uploading my app to the play store but now I can't upload my app. With the previous version of the expo sdk I used eas credentials and copied sha1 to the firebase console. Now with the expo 50 version I do the same and I get this error "this app is not authorized to use firebase authentication. Please verify that the correct packname, sha1 and sha256 are configured in the firebase console. a pla integrity token was passed, but no matching sha256 was registered in the firebase console.. please make sure that this applications packagename/sha256 pair is registered in the firebase console" copy the sha256 from eas credentials and paste it to firebase console and download google-services.json and return to compile everything and when I upload my .aab to the play store it tells me that my app does not load and is broken. Run it in local mode and it works. What is the error or is there something else I should do when using react native firebase?
I'm uploading about 6 versions of my application and it doesn't work, it only works in local mode. I have no idea and I'm stuck
